# LUDecomposition does not give the expected results

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Check this example:

```
A={{2, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, 2}};
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[A];
u = UpperTriangularize[lu];
l = ReplacePart[LowerTriangularize[lu], {i_, i_} -> 1];
lu2 = l.u;
lu2 === A
(*False*)
```

Am I missing here something? `l.u` should give back `A`

Comment: You forgot the permutation matrix. `IdentityMatrix[3][[p]].A == l.u` is the correct identity.

Comment: @J. M. what is the benefit in this case? to solve system of equation I need to have the form `A=L.U`. if I want to do this using your suggestion I have to find the inverse of `IdentityMatrix[3][[p]]` and you know finding the inverse is not desire and the whole idea behind `L.U` is not to do inverse of `A`

Comment: A permutation matrix is orthogonal. How are orthogonal matrices inverted? ;)

Comment: Aha, it is the Transpose.  but I still find it odd that MMA does not give L and U directly. any way, thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: The (partial) pivoting (and thus the permutation matrix) is necessary, since without it, there are a lot of nonsingular matrices that won't have a triangular decomposition. Consider this simple example: `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}`…